# Strange ViewPager behavior in ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-viewpager

I have created a ListView populated by a ArrayAdapter, in the adapter i'm trying to inflate a ViewPager on each row of the ListView.

The first row ViewPager is rendered well, as expected, but the others no, if i scroll down nothing happens but when i scroll back up the ViewPagers are rendered

Here is a piece of code of the ArrayAdapter (if needed i can add the rest)

```
  ViewPager mPager;
  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  
    Log.v(TAG, "getView in "+ position+" position");  

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);    
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);

    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.text_line);
    textView.setText(values[position]);

    mPager = (ViewPager) rowView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    AdapterPager mPagerAdapter = new AdapterPager(fragmentManager,values[position]);
    mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
    mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);

    return rowView;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

add code

```
mPager.setId(position + position)
```